# how to use single and double quote marks in php with brackets?

Tags: php, html

i have a problem using with single and double quotes with brackets in php

i have error near if condition please any one help

```
 $resonjob['Post_type']='Jobs';
    $resonjob['reason']='reasonstatus.php?job_id='.$row['job_id'];
    $nestedData[] = '<select onchange="reasonstatus(this.value)" style="width:80px;">
    <option value="'.$resonjob['reason'].'&type='.$resonjob['Post_type'].'&status=1" '.if($row['status']=='1'){.' selected;'.}.'>Active</option>
    <option value="'.$resonjob['reason'].'&type='.$resonjob['Post_type'].'&status=2" '.if($row['status']=='2'){.' selected;'.}.' >Inactive</option>
    </select>';
```

Comment: What is ur problem

Comment: i have error near if condition

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$resonjob['Post_type']='Jobs';
    $resonjob['reason']='reasonstatus.php?job_id='.$row['job_id'];
    $nestedData[] = '<select onchange="reasonstatus(this.value)" style="width:80px;">
    <option value="'.$resonjob['reason'].'&type='.$resonjob['Post_type'].'&status=1" '.($row['status']=='1' ? 'selected' : '').'>Active</option>
    <option value="'.$resonjob['reason'].'&type='.$resonjob['Post_type'].'&status=2" '.($row['status']=='2' ? ' selected' : '').' >Inactive</option>
    </select>';
```